# How to recognize individual radio buttons if they are added dynamically?

Tags: php, jquery, radio-button

I have two radio buttons: 'Yes' and 'No'. If I choose 'Yes' an input textbox will appear, and if I choose 'No' the textbox will be hidden.

**The problem is the radio buttons are added dynamically via a dropdown (numbers 1-30).**

They are currently setup like this:

```
<li>
    <input type="radio" id="yes-sdf-1" name="field[0][sdfradio]" value="Yes" />
    <label for="yes-sdf-1">Yes</label>
    <input type="text" name="field[0][sdf-text]" style="display: none;" />
</li>
<li>
    <input type="radio" id="no-sdf-1" name="field[0][sdfradio]" value="No" checked />
    <label for="no-sdf-1">No</label>
</li>
```

Here is my jQuery

```
$(':radio[name="sdfradio"]').change(function() {
    var sdfradio = $(this).filter(':checked').val();
    $('input#sdf-text').hide();
    if( sdfradio == 'Yes'){
        $('input#sdf-text').show();
        $('input#sdf-text').addClass("field required");
    }else if( sdfradio == 'No' ){
        $('input#sdf-text').hide();
    }

});
```

But as you can see, this can only work if there is one sdfradio. How do I let it work if I use an array like `name="field[count_goes_here][sdfradio]"`

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery **[`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)** for event delegation in case dynamically generated elements.

Also, use `*=` - jQuery **[attribute-contains selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/)**.

```
$(document).on('change',':radio[name*="sdfradio"]',function() {
    ....
});
```

---

I see no reference to `input` with ID `sdf-text`- `$('input#sdf-text')`.

You need `$(':text[name*="sdfradio"]')`